# How to login to Heroku within only one line?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'd like to know if there is a way to give credentials directly in login command in Heroku CLI ?

For now i'm doing like this :

```
heroku login
email : xxxx (user input)
password : xxxx (user input)
```

And I'd like to be able to do something in one line just like this :

```
heroku login email password
```

I searched in the documentation but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

I had confirmation that it is impossible with CLI.

BUT an enlightened reddit user suggested I use **Heroku platform API** instead of CLI since I'm scripting.

[Heroku Platform API Reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference)